# Gunicorn workers are unable to restart after timeout

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I have `gunicorn` serving a django application. `Nginx` is used as a reverse proxy. And `supervisord` is used to manage `gunicorn`.

This is the `supervisord` config:

```
command = /opt/backend/envs/backend/bin/gunicorn msd.wsgi:application --name backend --bind 13.134.82.143:8030 --workers 5 --timeout 300 --user backend --group backend --log-level info --log-file /opt/backend/logs/gunicorn.log

directory = /opt/backend/backend
user = backend
group = backend
stdout_logfile = /opt/backend/logs/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
```

Sometimes gunicorn workers time out. After that, I expect gunicorn to automatically reload the dead ones.

However, the strange thing is under heavy load, some workers cannot get back up saying:

```
Can't connect to ('13.134.82.143', 8030)
```

I think that the workers that timed out are left as a zombie and occupying the ports.

What can I do in such cases?

Comment: do share gunicorn , python , gevent versions you are using ? I also faced version incompatibility

Comment: also check nginx default timeouts as described in https://serverfault.com/questions/490101/how-to-resolve-the-gunicorn-critical-worker-timeout-error

Comment: @tom I am using python 3.4.3, gunicorn 19.6.0 and supervisord 3.0b2, not using gevent